# Dynamic C Linked List Implementation

Tags: c, linked-list

I've started to experiment with (void *) in C, in order to work with Dynamic Data Types, that is, to surpass the need to pass specific type of data.

I have implemented this doubly linked list in C and I tried to keep it versatile so it can hold and kind of data type (primitive and non-primitives). I'll be glad to have some feedback and ideas on how to improve my implementation.
as part of my path to study this subject I'm trying to create a mini library of common Data Structures like stacks, linked list, binary trees etc that will work with any kind of type.

here is the implementation of my doubly linked list.
I achieved "Dynamic" data type (I'm not sure if that's the correct term) by asking the user to provide constructor, destructor and comparison function for the objects that he'd like to store in the liist.
LinkedList.h

```
/* 
    Implements doubly linked list.

    ----------          ----------           ---------- 
    |  HEAD  | <------> |  NODE  | <------>  |  TAIL  | 
    ----------          ----------           ---------- 
    The linked list is generic and may hold any kind of data (from the same type!) given a proper constructor function for that type.

    Created by: @BAxBI as part of General DataStructure library for C.
 
*/
#ifndef __LINKED__LIST_H_
#define __LINKED__LIST__H_
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
    @brief Linked List item.
*/
typedef void * LItem;

/*
    @brief Constant Linked List item.
*/
typedef const void * CLItem;

/*
    @brief Linked List type.
*/
typedef struct LList * LList;


/* 
    Creates a new empty linked list 
    @param ctor Pointer to a constructor function for an element in the list. 
    @param dtor Pointer to a destructor function for an element in the list.
    @param compare Pointer to a comparison function between two elements in the list 
    @param print Pointer to a print function of an element in the list. 
    @return Pointer to an emty linked list 
*/
LList new_linked_list(LItem (*ctor)(LItem),void (*dtor)(LItem), int (*compare)(LItem, LItem), void (*print)(LItem));

/* 
    Adds a node to the head of the list.
    @param list The list to add the element to. 
    @param item A pointer to the item to add to the list.     
*/
void add_node(LList list, LItem item);

/*
    Deletes the first occurrence of an item in the list.
    @param list The list to delete the item from. 
    @param item The item to delete. 
*/
void delete_node(LList list, LItem item);

/* 
    Destroys a linked list and frees all the allocated memory. 
    @param list The linked list to destroy. 
*/
void destroy_linked_list(LList list);

/*
    Gets an element from the Linked List.
    @param list The list to get the element from.
    @param element The element to get from the list.
    @return The element from the list if exist NULL otherwise
*/
LItem get_element_from_LList(LList list, LItem element);

/*
    Gets the number of elements in the linked list.
    @param list The list the check its number of elements.
    @return The number of elements in the linked list.
*/
size_t get_No_elem_LList(LList list);

/*
    Prints the linked list (if given a print function to print a single element!)
    @param list The linked list to be printed.
*/
void print_list(LList list);


#endif
```

LinkedList.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

typedef struct Node{
    struct Node *prev_node;
    struct Node *next_node;
    LItem node_content;
}Node; 


struct LList {
    Node *head; 
    Node *tail; 
    size_t NoElements;
    // Functions provided by the client.
    LItem (*ctor)(LItem);
    void (*dtor)(LItem);
    int (*compare)(LItem, LItem);  
    void (*print)(LItem);
};

LList new_linked_list(LItem (*ctor)(LItem),void (*dtor)(LItem), int (*compare)(LItem, LItem), void (*print)(LItem)){
    LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof(struct  LList));
    if (!new_llist){
        return NULL;
    }
    new_llist->head = NULL;
    new_llist->tail = NULL;
    new_llist->NoElements = 0;

    new_llist->ctor = ctor;
    new_llist->dtor = dtor;
    new_llist->compare = compare;
    new_llist->print = print;

    return new_llist;
}


void add_node(LList list, LItem item){
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!new_node) return;
    new_node->next_node = NULL;
    new_node->prev_node = NULL;
    new_node->node_content = list->ctor(item);

    /* Empty list*/
    if(!list->head){
        list->head = new_node;
        list->tail = new_node;
    }
    else {
        new_node->next_node = list->head;
        list->head->prev_node = new_node;
        list->head = new_node;
    }
    list->NoElements++;
}

/* Deletes first occurence of a node in a linked list */
void delete_node(LList list, LItem item){
    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(list->compare(ptr->node_content, item) == 0){
            /* First node to be deleted */
            if(!ptr->prev_node){
                list->head = ptr->next_node;
            }
            else if(ptr->prev_node && ptr->next_node){
                ptr->next_node->prev_node = ptr->prev_node;
                ptr->prev_node->next_node = ptr->next_node;
            }
            else {
                ptr->prev_node->next_node = NULL;
            }
            if(list->dtor){
                list->dtor(ptr->node_content);
            }
            free(ptr);
            list->NoElements--;
            return;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next_node;
    }
}


void destroy_linked_list(LList list){
    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        Node *tmp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next_node;
        if(list->dtor){
            list->dtor(tmp->node_content);
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(list);
}

size_t get_No_elem_LList(LList list){
    return list->NoElements;
}

LItem get_element_from_LList(LList list, LItem element){
    Node *ptr = list->head;
    if(!list->head){
        printf("The list is empty!\n");
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        if(list->compare(ptr->node_content, element) == 0){
            return ptr->node_content;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next_node;
    }
    printf("The element you're looking for is not in the linked list.\n");
    return NULL;
}


void print_list(LList list){
    if(!list->print) {
        printf("The linked list provided doesn't have print function\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!list->head) {
        printf("The list is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr){
        list->print(ptr->node_content);
        if(ptr->next_node){
            printf(" <---> ");
        }
        else{
            printf(" ---> ");
        }
        ptr = ptr->next_node;
    }
    printf("\033[0;31m"); /* Red */
    printf("NULL\n");
    printf("\033[0m"); /* Reset */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'll be glad to have some feedback and ideas on how to improve my implementation.

Overall, A good presentation, yet any linked-list module needs to consider large scale usage.

**Bug: Incomplete linking update**

On deletion of the 1st node, code does `list->head = ptr->next_node;`, but does not update the 2nd nodes `.prev_node` member.

General thought: when a node is deleted, both the left node (or `LList`) and right node (or `LList`) need pointer updates, that's 2 links, never 1.

**Only works with pointers**

"work with **any kind of type**" and "asking the user to provide constructor, destructor and comparison function for the **objects** ..." --> With `typedef void * LItem;`, user can only use with object **pointer** types.  No pointer type checking is expected against `void *`.

**Name space**

`LinkedList.h` declares `__LINKED__LIST_H_, LItem, CLItem, LList, add_node, ..., print_list`.

Rather then scatter names, consider

`DLList.h` declares `__DLList_H_, DLList_Item, const DLList_Item, DLList, DLList_add, ..., DLList_print`.

**Casting `*alloc()`**

Casting the result of `*alloc()` not needed.  Be uniform.

```
LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof(struct  LList));  // OP did not cast here.
// Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

**Allocation failures not detectable by caller**

Consider returning a value.

```
//void add_node(LList list, LItem item){
//  Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
//  if (!new_node) return;

 // Return error flag
 bool add_node(LList list, LItem item){
  Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (!new_node) return true;
  ...
  return false;
}
```

**Use `const` when able**

```
// size_t get_No_elem_LList(LList list){
//  return list->NoElements;
// }
size_t get_No_elem_LList(const LList list){
  return list->NoElements;
}
```

**Omit console specialized code from `print_list()`**

Delete:

```
printf("\033[0;31m"); /* Red */
printf("\033[0m"); /* Reset */
```

**`get_element_from_LList()` error return**

`get_element_from_LList()` returns `NULL` when item not found, yet `NULL` may be a valid object added to the list.  Now caller does not distinguish success from failure.

I suppose caller could first try `get_No_elem_LList()`, yet I would prefer a different *get* interface, something the results in a `LItem` and a success indication.

**Use alternative than `printf()` to indicate errors**

For general purpose list list code, the functions (aside from `print_list()`) should **not** call `*printf()`.

Instead pass back to caller an error indication.

**Why double linked list??**

Tail access nor node deletion from the fail never occurs.
What was the point of a double linked list?

**No success indication**

I'd expect `delete_node()` to return something to indicate success/failure.

**Asymmetric functions**

`.dtor` is OK to be `NULL` with `if(list->dtor){ list->dtor(ptr->node_content); }`.

No such `NULL` test with `new_node->node_content = list->ctor(item);`

Documentation in .h file does not discuss this.

Consider instead with `new_linked_list()` to `NULL` test once, rather than repeatedly.

```
// new_llist->dtor = dtor;
new_llist->dtor = dtor ? dtor : dummy_function_that_does_nothing;
```

**Why `struct  LList`??**

Why code `LList` and `struct  LList`?  One is enough.

```
// LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof(struct  LList));`
LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof(LList));`
```

Even better, allocate to the size of the referenced object, not type.

```
LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof new_llist[0]);
// or
LList new_llist = calloc(1, sizeof *new_llist);
```

**Include `LinkedList.h` first**

The order of includes should be irrelevant, yet for `xxx.c`, the first include should be `xxx.h`.  This is a fine test that `xxx.h` does not rely on other include files.  `xxx.h` should itself include any needed include files.

```
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include "LinkedList.h"

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

**Missing sample code**

Consider a `main.c` that shows example usage.

**Tolerate `destroy_linked_list(NULL)`**

Just as `free(NULL)` is OK, consider adding `NULL` test.  This simplifies caller usage of `destroy_linked_list()`.

```
void destroy_linked_list(LList list){
  if (list) {
    ...
  }
```

**Compare function to take `const` arguments**

As `LItem` is a hidden pointer type (yech), use `const` so the same function used for `qsort()` can be used here.

```
// int (*compare)(LItem, LItem);  
int (*compare)(const LItem, const LItem);
```

Comment: There's a problem in that last recommendation - `const LItem` is `void *const`, not `const void *`, so you don't actually have a different signature.  That's one reason those typedefs are harmful.

Comment: @TobySpeight [True, true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRtB5B6grnA)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed comment. I am working to fix all the bugs error and innaccuracies you've mentioned. 
Specifically about the Data Type that it can handle, I see now what you mean. Is there a way to really make C function to accept *any* type of data?

thanks a lot!

Comment: @BarAmber "Is there a way to really make C function to accept any type of data?"  Yes, but the goal need details.  Clearly explain what does it mean to _accept_ and what does it _reject_. How much type checking? Let us say you want a DL list of `int`.  `add_node(list, 123);` should be OK, but what about `add_node(list, 5.0);`, `add_node(list, some_char_object);`, `add_node(list, NULL);`?  Right now, the DL routines gets/sets `void *`.  I suggest stay with that for now and get the other issues resolved.

Comment: I see. I've started already to work on the issues mentioned here, again thank you

Answer (score 5):

Include guard mismatch:

> ```
> #ifndef __LINKED__LIST_H_
> #define __LINKED__LIST__H_
> ```

Those two macros need to be identical!

---

<s>I don't see a need for `<stdlib.h>` in the header - what did I miss?</s>
`<stdlib.h>` is overkill just for `size_t` - prefer `<stddef.h>`.

---

I'm not really a fan of `typedef`s that hide pointers:

> ```
> typedef void * LItem;
> typedef const void * CLItem;
> typedef struct LList * LList;
> ```

The pointer-ness of these types is important to the code that uses them.

---

`new_linked_list()` uses `calloc()` to provide zero-initialise storage, but then overwrites all the members anyway.  That's a waste, compared to simply using `malloc()`.  (Remember that all-bytes zero doesn't portably make a null pointer).

---

`add_node()` has no way to indicate whether it succeeded or not.  That could cause serious breakage.

---

`delete_node()` doesn't tell the program whether or not the requested element was found and removed; this might be useful.

---

No need to cast here:

```
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

The return from `malloc` is a `void*`, which is convertible to any object pointer in C.  Also, I recommend using `sizeof` with an expression that matches the assignee:

```
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```

That has only a small benefit here, but a much larger one when assigning to a variable whose declaration is far away.

---

It's worth considering a "dummy head" node, so we can consolidate the "empty list" case.  That trades a small amount of storage for a big simplification of code.

---

In `delete_node()`, this looks like a good candidate for `for`:

> ```
>     Node *ptr = list->head;
>     while (ptr != NULL) {
>         ⋮
>         ptr = ptr->next_node;
>     }
> ```

---

Embedding terminal-specific escape codes into output (`printf("\033[0;31m")`) is distinctly non-portable, and can inhibit piping into other programs.  If you want programs to take advantage of terminal capabilities, use termcap or ncurses to generate the codes for the *actual* output device.

Comment: <dummy head" ned, so we can consolidate the "empty list" case> and "That trades a small amount of storage for a big simplification of code." --> Yes, but code may employ millions of linked-lists, _many_ of them empty.  Minimal space with empty lists is recommended.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "consider" rather than making a definite recommendation.  That said, it's possible to make the dummy head smaller than a real node - we can truncate to just the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is very clear and concise.
However, your naming does not make clear it is actually a doubly linked list.
So I would prefer `DLList`, `DLItem` and so forth.
Probably this is just WIP, but your `DLList` implementation is not complete, missing differentiation between head and rear accesses.

Your documentation comments just introduce repetition. Leave them away.
Example:

```
/* 
    Adds a node to the head of the list.
    @param list The list to add the element to. 
    @param item A pointer to the item to add to the list.     
*/
void add_node(LList list, LItem item);
```

The word `add` occurs 4 times. The word `list` appears 6 times. The word `node` is effectively repeated 5 times, counting also `item` and `element`, because the comment is not uniform. In 2 cases it uses `node` in 3 other cases it uses `item` respectively `element`.

To improve this, you could incorporate your doc comments in the variable naming.
E.g.: `LItem item_to_add`.

Here, we have the case what was mentioned in a previous answer. The pointer nature of `LItem` is hidden in the typedef. If that would not be the case the asterix before the variable naming would make it needless to document that `item` is a pointer.